# Add Multiple transparent JComponents objects to just one JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, jcomponent

This problem is bothering me a lot.

Suppose I have two different classes called `DrawProfile` and `PlotData`. These classes extend `JComponent`. I have also a `JPanel` called profile. I want to add first the `DrawProfile` to my profile `JPanel` and then I would like to add `PlotData` (`DrawProfile` and `PlotData` classes implement `paintComponent` method). `DrawProfile` class will draw some rectangular shapes which are filled by different colors. After that, `PlotData` which is just like a normal plot will sit on the top of `DrawProfile`(a rectangle with different colors). I want my `PlotData` to set its background according to `DrawProfile` different colorful shapes. It could be written a follows:

```
profile.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(profile));
profile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,650));
profile.add(new DrawProfile());
profile.add(new PlotData());
```

Note that I have used `profile.setOpaque()`, but it did not help me. I used         `AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f)` for `DrawProfile`. It works, but the problem is that the scatter plot colors are affected by `DrawProfile` objects, and the colors are not sharp. You can see my efforts [here](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7575/15743794386_b875787735_o.png). At the end I will add my main `JPanel` (profile) to the `JFrame`.

EDIT:
Regarding a runnable code, that would be hard. Because, the code might be intractable. 
To make my question clearer:

In `DrawProfile`, I extend the class by `JComponent`. I also implemeted `paintComponent()` method, where there is a `draw(Graphics g)` method inside the `paintComponent()` in order to draw multiple rectangulars with different colors. I set `AlphaComposite` to `0.5f` inside the `paintComponent()` method.

In `PlotData` class, I used `JFreechart` (XYplot), and this class extends `JPanel`. Within this class, there is a `paintComponent()` method which does plotting (I don't do any strange things here). Inside `paintComponent()`, I don't touch `AlphaComposite` (In fact, it is `1.0f`).

By doind above way, I was able to get my job done. but as you see in the link that I provided, PlotData objects do not have sharp colors.

NOTE that `PlotData` extends 'JPanel', while `DrawProfile` extends `JComponents`.

Please correct me if I am wrong. It seems that when we add `JComponents` objects to a `JPanel`, the first added `JComponent` object will be always stay on the top of the later added objects. For instance, in my provided example, I first added `DrawProfile`, so this class is sit on the top of my `PlotData` that I added it as my second `JComponent` object.

Comment: an you tried **setBackgroud(new Color(0,0,0,0));**

Comment: @subash Swing doesn't handle alpha based colors, components need to be either opaque or transparent, otherwise the paint system doesn't know it needs to prepare the graphics context before painting or that it should paint under the component, causing some weird and wonderful painting artefacts

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, there are lots of reasons that ts might be happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. `JFreechart` creates default background to draw a chart. What I did in the `paintComponent()` of `PlotData`, I set `chart.setBackgroundPaint(null);` ; and it solved my problem.